# EFS content not showing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pvc, storage-class

I'm running a Drupal application in POD that stores static file content in EFS using dynamic provisioning with PVC within the EKS cluster.

**Now I've created one new EKS cluster, and the Drupal application is running fine in this new EKS cluster, but it is not showing any file contents from EFS.**
I used existing EFS with dynamic provisioning so that the same contents could be accessed from both EKS clusters.

I need help to figure out why file contents are not visible from second cluster POD.
mounted path is same.